# How can I open a blf file by using python script?

Tags: python, python-can

<sub>I want to open a blf file using python scripts and print it. I have opened the file on wireshark. But when I open it using script and print it I do not get any output and there are no errors.</sub>

`These are a few environment details: os: windows, python 3.11.5, appdirs==1.4.4, attrs==23.1.0, canmatrix==1.0, click==8.1.7, colorama==0.4.6,dpkt==1.9.8, future==0.18.3, lxml==4.9.3, numpy==1.25.2, packaging==23.1, pyshark==0.6, python-can==4.2.2, pywin32==306, scapy==2.5.0, six==1.16.0, termcolor==2.3.0, typing_extensions==4.7.1, wrapt==1.15.0, IDE: Visual Studio code,` 
`file:Lines.blf, size: 21.8 MB, contains around 50000 in number`

```
import can

blf_file_path = "C:/Users/sahaanan/Desktop/blf_to_pcap/NewSW_7209_Lines.blf"

try:
    with open(blf_file_path, 'rb') as blf_file:
        log = can.BLFLogReader(blf_file)
        for msg in log:
            print(msg)

    if log.is_empty:
        print("The BLF file is empty.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error reading BLF file: {e}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get `can.BLFLogReader` from? According to the [doc](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/can/io/blf.html), you should be able to Read BLF files with `can.io.BLFReader`. Also `is_empty` doesn't seem to be a valid attribute. You can check if the object count is equal to 0 insted:

```
import can

blf_file_path = "C:/Users/sahaanan/Desktop/blf_to_pcap/NewSW_7209_Lines.blf"

try:
    with open(blf_file_path, 'rb') as blf_file:
        log = can.io.BLFReader(blf_file)
        for msg in log:
            print(msg)

        if log.object_count == 0:
            print("The BLF file is empty.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error reading BLF file: {e}")
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but it still does not solve my problem. There is  no output.

Comment: I can't help you without further debugging information. I tested the above code and was able to print all messages of a .blf file. Have you tried debugging by yourself? Set a break point to take a look at `log`. Also your blf file might be corrupt, can you read it with another program?

Comment: I have opened it on wireshark, but if it is corrupt how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you see any object in wireshark? What is `log.object_count`? This is basic debugging information that you should add to your question / comment.

Comment: I see packets on wireshark, I can see that there are 566289 packets. I am quiet new to this. I have tried to print log.object_count but it does not print anthing. As a matter of fact anything I print anything within the 'with' statement does not print.

Comment: Don't you even get an error message? The problem lies somewhere else and is not reproducible with the information you provided. Therefore I cannot help you further at this point.